# How to simplify this differentiated equation further?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The question I have is sqrt(2x-1) / 2e^3x and I am asked to differentiate and simplify.

This is my working below:

[image]

I am unsure of how to get to simplify this to get the final answer in the textbook shown below:

[image]
What do I have to do?

Comment: in the textbook answer, it should be $(2x-1)^{-1/2}\color{red}2e^{3x}-6e^{3x}(2x-1)^{\color{red}{(1/2)}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your result, since $\frac{e^{3x}}{3^{6x}} = e^{-3x}$, $(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x - 1)$ and $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x - 1}}$,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \frac{2e^{3x}\left((2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 3(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{4e^{6x}} \\
& = \frac{e^{-3x}\left((2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 3(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x - 1)\right)}{2} \\
& = \frac{e^{-3x}(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(1 - 3(2x - 1)\right)}{2} \\
& = \frac{e^{-3x}\left(1 - 6x + 3)\right)}{2\sqrt{2x - 1}} \\
& = \frac{e^{-3x}\left(2\left(2 - 3x\right)\right)}{2\sqrt{2x - 1}} \\
& = \frac{\left(2 -3x\right)e^{-3x}}{\sqrt{2x - 1}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This matches the final result shown for $g'(x)$ in $242$ in your image.

Comment: Thanks, where did you 1 - 3(2x-1) from?

Comment: @ChristopherU You're welcome. As I stated above, you have $(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x - 1)$. Using this, you get $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 3(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 3(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x - 1) = (2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1 - 3(2x - 1))$. In other words, I used that expression to replace the second term and then factored out the common factor of $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ to get the result you're asking about. To help make this more clear, I've updated my answer to show that intermediate step in the first RHS expression.

Comment: Thanks very much. This question might sound strange, but how did you  figure out that you need to split the (2x-1)^1/2 into (2x-1)^-1/2 times (2x-1) in order to simplify this? I spent quite a while pondering on this question and that did not come to my mind!

Comment: @ChristopherU The final result has a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x - 1}}$. As this is the same as $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, I need to find such a factor in the expression. As the first term in $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - 3(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ already has this factor, I need to find it in the second term. Due to how the sums of powers of exponents works, I know I can express this as $(2x - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(2x - 1)$ to get a factor of $(2x - 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ I can then take out, as I have done in my answer. Also, experience helps me see things like this.

Answer (score 1):

*A small trick !*

When you face expressions which only contain products, quotients, powers, exponentials, etc., logarithmic differentiation makes life much easier.

For your problem
$$y=\frac {\sqrt{2x-1}} {2e^{3x}}\implies \log(y)=\frac 12 \log(2x-1)-\log(2)-3x$$ Differentiating both sides
$$\frac {y'} y=\frac 12 \frac 2 {2x-1}-3= \frac 1 {2x-1}-3=\frac {2(2-3x)} {2x-1}$$ Now
$$y'=y \times\frac {y'} y=\frac {\sqrt{2x-1}} {2e^{3x}}\times \frac {2(2-3x)} {2x-1}=\frac{2-3x}{e^{3x} \sqrt{2x-1}}$$